# How to add some time to current time on request body?

Tags: postman

I want to add more time to the current time on the request body BUT I don't know how to. I have the following pre-request in a request A.

```
var moment = require('moment'); 
pm.environment.set('currenttime',moment().format(('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss+00:00')));
```

On request B, I have a param timestamp. I want to fill this param by `{{currenttime}} + somes minutes/ seconds`.

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this.

Request A: Pre-request:

```
const formatter = 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss+00:00';
const moment = require('moment'); 
pm.environment.set('currenttime',moment().format(formatter));
```

Request B: Pre-request

```
const formatter = 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss+00:00';
const moment = require('moment'); 
const currenttime = pm.environment.get('currenttime');

//Add 10 minutes
const parse = moment(currenttime, formatter).add(10, 'm');
pm.environment.set('currenttime', parse.format(formatter));
```

Comment: I have tried your way BUT my idea is add more time for a time variable. Example: I have a variable: "time":"2021-10-28T11:57:39+00:00". On request, I want to get this variable and add more some time for it. Your way isn't resolve my problem

Comment: @hanhnguyen you mean you just want to update value for one var `currenttime`, not a new var `futureTime`. So you just need `pm.environment.set('currenttime', parse.format(formatter));`

Comment: @hanhnguyen I've updated my answer to fit your situation.

Comment: Hi lucasnguyen17   Request A: Pre-request: const formatter = 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss+00:00';
const moment = require('moment'); 
pm.environment.set('currenttime',moment().format(formatter));            Request B: Pre-request: const formatter = 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss+00:00';
const currenttime = pm.environment.get('currenttime');

//Add 10 minutes
const parse = moment(currenttime, formatter).add(10, 'm');
pm.environment.set('currenttime', parse.format(formatter));               BUT error displays: "There was an error in evaluating the Pre-request Script:ReferenceError: moment is not defined"

Comment: I think it doesn't found "moment" on the Request B

Comment: @hanh yeah. My bad. Updated my answer one more time. Hope  no issue left